# How to clear ActionBar NavigationListMenu onPause() of fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

Currenty, I have an activity with seven different child fragments in my android app. One of the fragment has to navigate a list menu but others do not have to navigate it or show it.

Frankly speaking, I don't want the other fragments use the NavigationListMode, however it will be activated also in all other fragments.

> Is there anyway to perform this operation in Sherlock ActionBar Fragments?

[image]

I used the code snippet below to remove it for others, but I've never succeded (at anything what I have tried).

```
public class Fragment_Success extends SherlockListFragment implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
{
  @Override
  public void onPause() 
  {
    super.onPause();
    //academic_year_list.clear(); // Unsupported operation exception returned
    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getNavigationMode();
    getSherlockActivity().closeOptionsMenu();
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle   savedInstanceState)
  {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fragment_success, container, false);

    ...

    String[] academic_year_array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.academic_year);
    Context context = getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> academic_year_list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.academic_year, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    academic_year_list.setDropDownViewResource(com.actionbarsherlock.R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(academic_year_list, this);
    ...
    return rootView;
   }
  ...
 }
```

Comment: why don't you just change the navigation mode inside the fragment onCreateView() or in the onResume(). it might work.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to change the mode in other fragments. When I've tried that, I got  error by writing `getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getNavigationMode();getSherlockActivity().closeOptionsMenu();`. Does it be nullable?

Comment: getSherlockActivity() inside onPause may return null in some android versions.
but inside the onCreateView() it won't return null, have you tried using it inside the onCreateView() ? or the onResume()?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added `getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().getNavigationMode();
        getSherlockActivity().getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);` inside `onCreateView()` methods of the all other fragments and it worked. Thanks again.